# Build multiple configurations of a project in a single build operation in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I'm trying to build an XPCOM extension for Firefox, and I need to build separate dlls for Firefox 4 and Firefox 5, to link against their different versions of the xulrunner SDK. Is there some way that I can do this using a single vcproj to generate two output files from different configurations of a single project? The only difference between the configurations is the directory of the xulrunner SDK in the include and lib paths.

As far as I can tell, VS2010 will only build one configuration at a time. I've tried adding a new platform for the project, but it will only let me add predefined platforms (x64, Itanium).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment since there has to be a better way, but one hack I've seen done is to make a copy of the project file under a new name, add that as well to the solution file, and alter the settings for one of the copies, you then basically have two projects that include the same files, but with different settings. Creates a maintenance nightmare though, you need to keep them in sync, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking the question in hopes of avoiding duplicating the project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try going to Build->Configurations Manager. You can define multiple build configurations there and then build whichever ones you'd like using Build->Batch Build. Is this what you're asking about?

(BTW, first post! Yay!)

EDIT: I should add that this works in VS2008, which is the only VS I have installed here, but the feature is still available in VS2010.

Comment: That works, but I'm still searching for a more convenient way.. I'll update if I find anything pleasanter.

Comment: add a keyboard shortcut for batch build.